# Format the look and feel of an actual List without using any web part in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Can anyone please tell me if there is anyway to format(atleast add gridlines) to a list without actually creating a new page or inserting any web part? I'm using many workflows and I have connected multiple lists using them to get a final view. Creating a new page for each list and trying to insert a webpart to provide EDIT user interface is really getting cumbersome for me.

My Scenario:

I have 2 lists:

1. List 1: Level 1 users can EDIT this list (add/update/delete items in the list)
2. List 2: Level 2 users can EDIT this list (add/update/delete items).

List 1 and List 2 are interconnected through workflows. 
And the final View is a non editable view only for END USERS to view.

Now my concern is, the Level 1 UI and Level 2 UI are very simple and plain(default DataSheet View), I was wondering if there is any way to add some format to it using Designer.(Other than Standard or DataSheet View).

Comment: Use JSLink and achieve the desired UI

Comment: As suggested by @Deepmala Try to use SharePoint Client Side Rendering (JSLink). Using this you can render you view as per your wish.. But for this you will have to add a path/link/reference of you Javascript file in your list view web part property.

Comment: Refer this link - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only built in formatting is available in the "modify view" page under style (I think it is). One of them, I forget which, will at least give a shaded background for alternating rows. There are other good ones in there too.

Sorry for all the "I think" and "I forget" comments but I don't have an instance in front of me to look. Hope that helps though!